# algebra related question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i meet  following problem and want to clarify   it's statement.problem is following

to reproduce an old photograph,a photographer   charges x dollars to make a negative.$3x/5$ dollars for each of first $10$ prints and $x/5$ dollars for each print in excess of $10$ prints.if $45$ is the total charge to make a negative  and 20 prints from  an old photograph,what is  the value of $x$?
I don't understand one thing,   if  it takes  $3x/5$ dollar for each of first $10$ prints,then it will take $10*3*x/5$  or $6*x$ dollar right? but what does mean in excess of $10$?if it is additional  printing,   and because we have $10+10=20$ and also total number of   charge to make negative,we may would  have $6*x+2*x=45$  or $8x=45$  so $x=5.625$ but in answers list there is only  value $5$,maybe i misunderstand problem,so please help

Comment: I've removed [tag:algebra] tag, since we don't use algebra tag anymore, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3081#3081) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only missed the negative, what costs $x$. So we have
$$x+6x+2x=45$$

Comment: so it means that $x=5$?  aaa yes  it is because of  translation problem from english,thanks a lot of

Answer (score -1):

The mistake was that you missed the negative one i.e. $8x+x=45 \Rightarrow 9x=45 \Rightarrow x=5$.